# How to use FCM in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using eclipse, In earlier days I have used Google Cloud Messaging for push notifications but now they were changed to Fire-base Cloud Messaging. If anyone know any solution to implement Fire-base Cloud Messaging in eclipse itself please let me know.Thanks in advance :)

Comment: No, FCM can't use in Eclipse..Convert your project to Android Studio!!

Comment: I suggest you to use FCM in Android studio.

Comment: Oh okay thank you @ Nikunj Paradva and @ Shoeb Siddique